# I have no idea how to make this IF statement work in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, if-statement, conditional-statements, case

I'm writing a code which goal is matching a name from one table to a name in other table. However all names in the both tables were given by a multiple people from different parts of country and are a little bit chaotic. For example a blue lamp in the one table would be written as a "02 BLUE LAMP (lamp)" or "02 BLMP (lamp)" or "02 (lamp)" or and in the other table as a "02 LAMP" or "02 BLUE LAMP). So idea behind my code if first compare two entries gradually, first by name (one in caps) and then by type (one in parenthesis). I already programed comparison by full name.
However in some cases there are several items labeled as type "(lamp)", so I want firstly compare by number "(02)" and type "(lamp)" [using IF number = l_number THEN] and then by the type only [ELSIF number <> l_number THEN] therefore conditions are same in both cases. So if there is one item with type "(lamp)", but the numbers don't match its ID still gets matched, but if there is multiple items with type (lamp) only ones that have same number "(02)" and type "(lamp)":

```
--above this there is code irrelevant to discussion 
         RETURN l_retval;
           EXCEPTION
           WHEN no_data_found THEN

               BEGIN  
               SELECT
                   ID
               INTO l_retval
               FROM OBJECTS_MV
               WHERE TS_ID = p_ts_id
                    IF number = l_number THEN
                                (upper(number_name) LIKE '%LAMP%' AND upper(l_type) LIKE '%LAMP%') OR
                                (upper(number_name) LIKE '%CHAIR%' AND upper(l_type) LIKE '%CHAIR%') OR
                    ELSIF number <> l_number THEN
                                (upper(number_name) LIKE '%LAMP%' AND upper(l_type) LIKE '%LAMP%') OR
                                (upper(number_name) LIKE '%CHAIR%' AND upper(l_type) LIKE '%CHAIR%') OR
                    END IF;
                    
               RETURN l_retval;
               EXCEPTION
               WHEN no_data_found THEN     
--code continues, but it is irrelevant to discussion
```

My college told me that I already used too many SELECT and that is apparently slowing down the website, so ideally solution would only have one SELECT.

I genuinely have no idea how to solve this after hours of breaking my mind on it. I tired different solutions I tried with case with little success. Only error I got was that statement wasn't closed properly. Hope my explanation makes sense.

Thanks in advance

Comment: The RIGHT way to do this is to scrub your data store so that the names are consistent.  Take the time once to fix the misspellings, and then data analysis becomes easy.

Comment: You'll never to need to deal with `'HAIR'` or `'CLAMP'`, right? Ordering the comparisons from longest to shortest strings might handle those cases, but it isn't pretty.

Comment: @TimRoberts it has 2 million rows and project has to be done by the end of the year

Comment: Even so, there are probably a relatively small number of misspellings (like, dozens).  If you know what things to expect, you can have a script show you the rejected lines.  Fix the next misspelling globally, then iterate.

Comment: @TimRoberts it isn't about misspelling. It is about different people from different parts of country naming thing differently for decades. Sometimes same chair will be named "02 blue chair (chair)" and sometimes as "02 (chair)" or "02 CHR" or "02 (chair)". Yeah it would be nice if I could globally fix this, however this isn't really about misspelling it is about people not sticking to any naming convention. Also I'm not working with something as simple as furniture. This is merely a placeholder to stay anonymous. Trust me when I say it can't be help. Thanks for suggestion though.

Comment: @HABO that is a genius idea

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `CASE...WHEN` expression, something like this:

```
 WHERE TS_ID = p_ts_id
  and CASE 
         WHEN number = l_number THEN
             CASE WHEN (upper(number_name) LIKE '%LAMP%'  
                        AND upper(l_type) LIKE '%LAMP%'
                       )
                       OR 
                      (upper(number_name) LIKE '%CHAIR%' 
                       AND upper(l_type) LIKE '%CHAIR%') 
                  THEN 1
                  ELSE 0
             END
          ELSE /* number <> l_number */
             CASE WHEN (upper(number_name) LIKE '%LAMP%'  
                        AND upper(l_type) LIKE '%LAMP%'
                       )
                       OR 
                      (upper(number_name) LIKE '%CHAIR%' 
                       AND upper(l_type) LIKE '%CHAIR%') 
                  THEN 1
                  ELSE 0
              END
        END=1

   END
```

But your THEN part is the same as ELSE..IF..THEN part so I don't understand the logic: you need to adapt this syntax to your logic.

Answer (score 0):

It is frequently easier to use boolean logic in a where clause, and it appears to me that as both sets of string comparisons are exactly the same that it doesn't matter if `number = l_number` or if `number <> l_number` unless you want to exclude rows when l_number is null

```
SELECT
   ID
INTO l_retval
FROM OBJECTS_MV
WHERE TS_ID = p_ts_id
AND (
        (upper(number_name) LIKE '%LAMP%' AND upper(l_type) LIKE '%LAMP%')
     OR
        (upper(number_name) LIKE '%CHAIR%' AND upper(l_type) LIKE '%CHAIR%') 
    )
-- AND l_number IS NOT NULL -- optional, this isn't clear
```

---

"*I want to first match by number and type if there aren't any cases matches I then want to match by type only*"

It is possible that you actually need 2 queries to meet that latest clarification, but you might use a case expression to qualify the results like this:

```
SELECT
   ID
   , case when number = l_number then 0
          when number <> l_number then 1
          else 3
     end as priority
INTO l_retval
FROM OBJECTS_MV
WHERE TS_ID = p_ts_id
AND (
        (upper(number_name) LIKE '%LAMP%' AND upper(l_type) LIKE '%LAMP%')
     OR
        (upper(number_name) LIKE '%CHAIR%' AND upper(l_type) LIKE '%CHAIR%') 
    )
-- AND l_number IS NOT NULL -- optional, this isn't clear
```

Comment: I want to first match by number and type if there aren't any cases matches I then want to match by type only

Comment: working with just what you included in the question:  you have the EXACT SAME conditions under `IF number = l_number` and `ELSIF number <> l_number` so that means it does not matter what what non-null value `number` is.  If you had different conditions under (say) `ELSIF number <> l_number`  then you could structure the boolean logic to include a predicate involving `number`

Comment: What "sql" is this for? Oracle?  Every database vendor has a very different sql flavour so you should tag you question with that database (in preference to "sql") i.e. Avoid "sql" as a tag unless the question relates purely to the sql standard.